# Gradle generate Asynce(RPC) and i18n for GWT-projects like as maven-gwt-plugin do

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gradle, gwt-maven-plugin

Our team wants to migrate a gwt maven project to Gradle.

We use gwt-maven-project as plugin to generate RPC source and i18n messages.

It seems almost none dependable Gradle plug-in like gwt-maven-plugin for gradle project.

Except exec task that call maven command, have another resolution?